# CLI equivalent of web UI operations: "mark success" with "past", "mark failed" with "downstream", etc

Tags: airflow

In the Airflow web UI, I can mark a task instance as "success" or "failed", along with all instances of that same task across past DAG runs.

As another example, I can mark a task instance as "success", along with all "downstream" tasks within the same DAG, as well as all instances of those tasks in future DAG runs.

What are the CLI equivalents of these kinds of operations? Is there no single interface for manipulating batches of tasks as in the web UI?